# Spinner se ve oscuro en PopUp Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, recyclerview, popup

Tengo un problema con un spinner que no se muestra de forma correcta en la interfaz, el spinner esta en un pop-up que ocupa gran parte de la pantalla, al lado del spinner hay un image-button.
El spinner cuando lo oprimo se ve de color gris oscuro, adjunto imagen de como se ve:
[image: VISTA DEL SPINNER OSCURO]

Codigo del xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:alpha="50"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="6dp"
tools:context=".PopUpElegirActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp_popUp_Elegir"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnBuscar_popUp_Elegir"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/b_circular_amarillo"
        android:contentDescription="@string/btn_popup_Elegir"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24" />

</LinearLayout>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rcv_popUp_Elegir"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

Codigo del popUp:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop_up_elegir);
    DisplayMetrics medidasVentana = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(medidasVentana);
    int ancho = medidasVentana.widthPixels;
    int alto = medidasVentana.heightPixels;
    getWindow().setLayout((int)(ancho*0.85), (int)(alto*0.8));
    spElegir = findViewById(R.id.sp_popUp_Elegir);
    ImageButton btnBuscar = findViewById(R.id.btnBuscar_popUp_Elegir);
    inicializarFirebase();
    spinnerAdap();
}
//INICIAR FIREBASE
private void inicializarFirebase() {
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(PopUpElegirActivity.this);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    dataref = database.getReference();
}

//ADAPTER SPINNER
private void spinnerAdap(){
    String[] product = {"EMPANADA", "BEBIDA", "COMBO", "INSUMOS", "OTROS"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(PopUpElegirActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_item_tipo, product);
    spElegir.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

//OMITIR
No puedo subir mi pregunta a menos que tenga más texto, asdasdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasd asdasdasdasd asdasdasdasd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes definir un color de fondo en tu `Spinner` usando `android:background` por ejemplo usando un color transparente serìa:

```
 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/sp_popUp_Elegir"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Comment: Lo intente pero solo quedan en blanco las palabras, el espacio que sobra sigue viendose gris oscuro.